# Can I mail jars of mole sauce?

Tags: food-safety

I'd love to send my friends and family homemade mole sauce in jars for Christmas because we can't be together over the holidays thanks to covid.  Has anyone done this before?  I'm worried about the sauce going bad in the mail.

Comment: Are you talking about fully prepared liquid sauce, or a paste like what's sold in stores?

Comment: Check with UPS or FedEx, I believe you can send perishables in insulated boxes with ice packs in it. Though I don't know if it is necessary or not.

Comment: Welcome to SA! See my answer below.  How practical this is partly depends on where you live.

Answer (score 1):

Most mole sauces are not particularly perishable, and would be fine for several days at room temperature.  If it has a high salt content, it could be fine for weeks.  Further, in the Northern Hemisphere it's currently winter, so if you live on this side of the planet you don't really have to worry about the jar being exposed to high temperatures.  Tips:

1. Ship using a carrier who will reliably deliver in 3 days or less
2. Make sure there is "headroom" in the jars, so that if the mole freezes it doesn't crack the jar
3. Pad the jar with at least two layers of distinct padding, for example bubble wrap surrounded by crushed paper.
4. If it's not winter where you are, then you'll want to line the box with insulation and enclosed some ice packs to make sure that the mole doesn't heat up, which could cause it to go bad in less than a day
5. Avoid mole recipes that include fresh, uncooked fruit purees or pastes; a mole where all ingredients are cooked together for an hour or more is ideal
6. Label the box "perishble, open and refrigerate immediately"